# Getting console error to return false

Tags: javascript

Write a function called "isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive".

Given a number, in this case an age, "isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive" returns whether a person of this given age is old enough to legally drink and drive in the United States.

Notes:
* The legal drinking age in the United States is 21.
* It is always illegal to drink and drive in the United States.

```
var output = isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(22);
console.log(output); // --> false
```

Starter Code:

```
function isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(age) {
  // your code here
}
```

My solution:

```
function isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(age) {
  // your code here
  var output = age >= 21;
  console.log(output); 
  return output;
}

var output = isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(21);
```

The error I am getting while submitting the result is below.

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTiIS.png)

Can someone please help?

Comment: On my country you just need to `return false;` from this function

Comment: Hint: **It is always illegal to drink and drive in the United States.** What age do you think would change that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this look like a trick question, thus not a "real" programing related question

Comment: @AlonEitan this question is from HackReactor and I am getting this error while submitting. So I haven't got the answer, so no need to close it.

Comment: @pkrunalc I don't think this is a low quality question, it's just the body of the question - It's against the law to drink and drive, so it just look like a weird question - Like "What is the minimum age one can kill their own mother?" It seem that you return the correct result age-wise, but there is this legal issue which is off-topic

Comment: i have created codepen and it looks fine https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Omjmvo?editors=1111

Comment: if you pass 22, it should true and below 21 , it should return false , if I am not wrong ..please check my codepen

Comment: @NagaSaiA thanks for creating one even the similar JsFiddle, and everything looks normal (https://jsfiddle.net/ne77j351/) I am getting an error while submitting it to HackReactor website.

Answer (score 2):

your code should return `false` considering it's *always* illegal to drink and drive in the US.

```
return false;
```

Comment: why should they?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw It might because of any condition might not being satisfy. Even I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should always return false, so why not just return FALSE (since **its always illegal to drink and drive in the US**)?

Anyways, your code is returning TRUE since age of 21 is greater than or EQUAL TO (in this case) the drinking age of 21. However the result does not have anything to do with the passed parameter.

Comment: Well, I am still getting an error. check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/ne77j351/1/

Comment: I think you're over thinking it a little bit. The result has nothing to do with the supplied parameter, you could simply just return FALSE. `function isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(age) {
  return output;
}

var output = isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(21);`

Comment: Sorry made a mistake on my comment `function isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(age) { return FALSE; } var output = isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(21);` what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Still it didn't worked. Getting an error "ReferenceError: FALSE is not defined"

Comment: `return false;` not been using js recently and habits caught up with me :p

Answer (score 1):

In pure JS, your code works well. Result from console: [image]

But i think you take the data from the form like a string type. And you should convert it to Int before comparison:

```
function isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(age) {
  age = age ? parseInt(age) : 0;
  var output = (age >= 21);
  console.log(output); 
  return output;
}

var output = isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(21);
```

But **right answer for this question** is code like this:

```
function isOldEnoughToDrinkAndDrive(age) {
  return false;
}
```

Because: **It is always illegal to drink and drive in the United States.**

Comment: Then just convert input age to integer type like inside my version of code

Comment: Then right answer for code of this function is always:  return false;

Comment: I know, but it isn't working or I could say some of the condition might not being satisfy..